# How to use your own DLL with a derived class with params for beginners

Tags: c++, qt, dll, interface, shared-libraries

I have problem with my DLL. I created a Library project in QT with this information:

MyProject_global.h:

```
#ifndef MYPROJECT_GLOBAL_H
#define MYPROJECT_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(MYPROJECT_LIBRARY)
#  define MYPROJECT_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define MYPROJECT_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // MYPROJECT_GLOBAL_H
```

MyProject.h

```
#ifndef MYPROJECT_H
#define MYPROJECT_H

#include "MyProject_global.h"
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QDebug>

//trying to do an Interface in dll
class MYPROJECT_EXPORT MyProject
{
public:
    virtual ~MyProject();
    virtual void save(QString path) = 0;
};

#endif // MYPROJECT_H
```

MyProject.cpp

```
#include <MyProject.h>

MyProject::~MyProject(){
    qDebug()<<"destructor core";
};
```

Base.h

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

#include <MyProject.h>

class MYPROJECT_EXPORT Base : public MyProject
{
public:
    Base();
    ~Base();
    virtual void save(QString path) override;

protected:
    QString name;
    QDate date;
    QTime hour, pass;

};

#endif // BASE_H
```

Base.cpp

```
#include "Base.h"

Base::Base()
{
    qDebug()<<"base constructor";
}

Base::~Base(){
    qDebug()<<"destructor base";
}

void Base::save(QString path){
    qDebug()<<"Save"<<path;
}
```

Derived.h

```
#ifndef DERIVED_H
#define DERIVED_H

#include <compfolder/Base.h>

class MYPROJECT_EXPORT Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(QString name, QDate date, QTime hour, QTime pass);
    Derived();
    ~Derived();
};

#endif // DERIVED_H
```

Derived.cpp

```
#include "Derived.h"

Derived::Derived(QString name, QDate date, QTime hour, QTime pass) : Base()
{
    qDebug()<<"derived constructor";
}
Derived::Derived(){
    qDebug()<<"derived without params";
}
Derived::~Derived()
{
    qDebug()<<"destructor derived";
}
```

Then I created another project that uses this DLL. I imported the lib and the header files:

```
INCLUDEPATH += \
    E:/QT/MYPROJECT/MyProject \
LIBS+= \
    -LE:/QT/MYPROJECT/build-MyProject-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MSVC2019_64bit/release -lMyProject \
```

So, In main I have:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QDate date;
    date.setDate(2021,04,28);
    QTime time,pass;
    time.setHMS(0,0,0);
    pass.setHMS(0,0,0);

    Base b;
    Derived d;
    qDebug()<<"step0";
    Derived de("hello",date,time,pass);
    qDebug()<<"crashed";
  
}
```

The output is:

```
base constructor
base constructor
derived without params
step0
base constructor
derived constructor
15:06:49: The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

The problem is in the line "Derived de ("hello",date, time, pass);" if I delete it, it works. I don't understand why the program has unexpectedly finished.

---

Edited:
I found the error.
When I debug I obtain:
Critical error detected c0000374.
The problem was in the literal "hello". I created a QString variable:

```
QString test="hello";
Derived de(test,date,time,pass);
```

And it works, but really I dont understand why I can't pass "hello" directly.

Comment: Are you using the release library in release configuration?

Comment: The lines `step0` `derived constructor` `base constructor` are coming out in a funny order as `base constructor` should be output before `derived constructor`

Comment: Hi Richard Critten! thanks for answering. Yes, im going to change the last lines, I copied and paste in wrong position, base constructor is before to derived  constructor.
Hi drescherjm!, thanks for answering. I'm working with the release library.

Answer (score 0):

Why base doesn't call MyProject constructor?

Comment: When you post in the Answer section you are supposed to provide the "Answer". I think its undefined behavior caused by mixing debug and release binaries of msvc but the person asking has disappeared. The code to me looks fine.